# android external applications are not able to access file from internal location

Tags: android, file, fileoutputstream

I am creating my file inside a temporary folder in my internal memory location. I am then sending this URI in an intent to other applications and they are not able to open the file from this location. However, if I save the file in my internal memory location and pass he internal memory URI, the file is accessible. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the file in another application you have to store (copy) it to a public location first and then send the URI of this public location to the other application. See [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

And while creating files in Intenal Memory make sure you use MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to give access to other applications to read.

```
openFileOutput("myfile", MODE_WORLD_READABLE )
```